# Find weighted random row. Or split 1 row into many based on column value

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I want to query the DB and pick a random item weighted by the count. Something like so:

```
SELECT * FROM (-- SUBQUERY THAT GENERATES WEIGHTED TABLE --)
    ORDER BY ct * RAND() LIMIT 1
```

I'm thinking the following might be a good approach.  I have a table that looks something like this:

```
| id  | item   | count |
| --- | ------ | ----- |
| 1   | item a | 3     |
| 2   | item b | 2     |
| 3   | item c | 4     |
```

How can I query the database so that 1 row is shown per count? I.e. like this:

```
| id  | item   | count |
| --- | ------ | ----- |
| 1   | item a | 3     |
| 1   | item a | 3     |
| 1   | item a | 3     |
| 2   | item b | 2     |
| 2   | item b | 2     |
| 3   | item c | 4     |
| 3   | item c | 4     |
| 3   | item c | 4     |
| 3   | item c | 4     |
```

In case it helps, I've created a DB fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wRZgBYkDM18c5fk7tgkBkA/0

I'm using MariaDB 10.0.

Comment: What is the purpose of the resulting set of rows?

Comment: @RickJames I want to query the DB and pick a random item weighted by the count. Something like so: `SELECT * FROM (-- SUBQUERY THAT GENERATES WEIGHTED TABLE --) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of proliferating the number of rows, let's add a cumulative total:

```
| id  | item   | count | cumm_tot
| --- | ------ | ----- |
| 1   | item a | 3     |  3
| 2   | item b | 2     |  5
| 3   | item c | 4     |  9
```

Then get the last number, 9, for use below.
Index the new column.
Fetch random item thus:

```
WHERE    cumm_tot > 9 * RAND()
ORDER BY cumm_tot
LIMIT 1
```

To set the column and get the `9`, perform this task:

```
SET @c := 0;
UPDATE tbl
    SET cumm_tot = (@c := @c + `count`)
    ORDER BY id;
-- @c will now be the total (9)
```

Whenever you add items or change the weights, rerun the two statements above.

(This code should work on any version of MySQL/MariaDB.  There may be a "window function" that works better in new versions.)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM thing ORDER BY RAND()/ct LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Always try to write down to some explanation statement of the code. For better understanding to other professional.